# Deadlock in Python's multiprocessing upon early termination

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm creating a `multiprocessing.Queue` in Python and adding `multiprocessing.Process` instances to this `Queue`.

I would like to add a function call that is executed after every `job`, which checks if a specific task has succeeded. If so, I would like to empty the `Queue` and terminate execution.

My `Process` class is:

```
class Worker(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, queue, check_success=None, directory=None, permit_nonzero=False):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.check_success = check_success
        self.directory = directory
        self.permit_nonzero = permit_nonzero
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        for job in iter(self.queue.get, None):
            stdout = mbkit.dispatch.cexectools.cexec([job], directory=self.directory, permit_nonzero=self.permit_nonzero)
            with open(job.rsplit('.', 1)[0] + '.log', 'w') as f_out:
                f_out.write(stdout)
            if callable(self.check_success) and self.check_success(job):
                # Terminate all remaining jobs here
                pass
```

And my `Queue` is setup here:

```
class LocalJobServer(object):

    @staticmethod
    def sub(command, check_success=None, directory=None, nproc=1, permit_nonzero=False, time=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if check_success and not callable(check_success):
            msg = "check_success option requires a callable function/object: {0}".format(check_success)
            raise ValueError(msg)

        # Create a new queue
        queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
        # Create workers equivalent to the number of jobs
        workers = []
        for _ in range(nproc):
            wp = Worker(queue, check_success=check_success, directory=directory, permit_nonzero=permit_nonzero)
            wp.start()
            workers.append(wp)
        # Add each command to the queue
        for cmd in command:
            queue.put(cmd, timeout=time)
        # Stop workers from exiting without completion
        for _ in range(nproc):
            queue.put(None)
        for wp in workers:
            wp.join()
```

The function call `mbkit.dispatch.cexectools.cexec()` is a wrapper around `subprocess.Popen` and returns `p.stdout`.

In the `Worker` class, I've written the conditional to check if a job succeeded, and tried emptying the remaining jobs in the `Queue` using a `while` loop, i.e. my `Worker.run()` function looked like this:

```
def run(self):
    for job in iter(self.queue.get, None):
        stdout = mbkit.dispatch.cexectools.cexec([job], directory=self.directory, permit_nonzero=self.permit_nonzero)
        with open(job.rsplit('.', 1)[0] + '.log', 'w') as f_out:
            f_out.write(stdout)
        if callable(self.check_success) and self.check_success(job):
            break
    while not self.queue.empty():
        self.queue.get()
```

Although this works sometimes, it usually deadlocks and my only option is to `Ctrl-C`. I am aware that `.empty()` is unreliable, thus my question.

Any advice on how I can implement such an early termination functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have a deadlock here. It is just linked to the behavior of `multiprocessing.Queue`, as the `get` method is blocking by default. Thus when you call `get` on an empty queue, the call stall, waiting for the next element to be ready. You can see that some of your workers will stall because when you use your loop `while not self.queue.empty()` to empty it, you remove all the `None` sentinel and some of your workers will block on the empty `Queue`, like in this code:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue
q = Queue()
for e in iter(q.get, None):
    print(e)
```

To be notified when the queue is empty, you need to use non blocking call. You can for instance use `q.get_nowait`, or use a timeout in `q.get(timeout=1)`. Both throw a `multiprocessing.queues.Empty` exception when the queue is empty. So you should replace your `Worker` `for job in iter(...):` loop by something like:

```
while not queue.empty():
    try:
        job = queue.get(timeout=.1)
    except multiprocessing.queues.Empty:
        continue
    # Do stuff with your job
```

If you do not want to be stuck at any point.

For the synchronization part, I would recommend using a synchronization primitive such as [`multiprocessing.Condition`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Condition) or an [`multiprocessing.Event`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Event). This is cleaner than the Value are they are design for this purpose. Something like this should help

```
def run(self):
    while not queue.empty():
        try:
            job = queue.get(timeout=.1)
        except multiprocessing.queues.Empty:
            continue
        if self.event.is_set():
            continue
        stdout = mbkit.dispatch.cexectools.cexec([job], directory=self.directory, permit_nonzero=self.permit_nonzero)
        with open(job.rsplit('.', 1)[0] + '.log', 'w') as f_out:
            f_out.write(stdout)
        if callable(self.check_success) and self.check_success(job):
            self.event.set()
    print("Worker {} terminated cleanly".format(self.name))
```

with `event = multiprocessing.Event()`.

Note that it is also possible to use a `multiprocessing.Pool` to get avoid dealing with the queue and the workers. But as you need some synchronization primitive, it might be a bit more complicated to set up. Something like this should work:

```
 def worker(job, success, check_success=None, directory=None, permit_nonzero=False):
      if sucess.is_set():
          return False
      stdout = mbkit.dispatch.cexectools.cexec([job], directory=self.directory, permit_nonzero=self.permit_nonzero)
      with open(job.rsplit('.', 1)[0] + '.log', 'w') as f_out:
          f_out.write(stdout)
      if callable(self.check_success) and self.check_success(job):
          success.set()
      return True

# ......
# In the class LocalJobServer
# .....

def sub(command, check_success=None, directory=None, nproc=1, permit_nonzero=False):

    mgr = multiprocessing.Manager()
    success = mgr.Event()

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(nproc)
    run_args = [(cmd, success, check_success, directory, permit_nonzero)]
    result = pool.starmap(worker, run_args)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Note here that I use a Manager as you cannot pass `multiprocessing.Event` directly as arguments. You could also use the arguments `initializer` and `initargs` of the `Pool` to initiate global `success` event in each worker and avoid relying on the `Manager` but it is slightly more complicated.

Comment: Great response, thanks for that. A rather basic question, would you recommend the `multiprocessing.Pool` over my current approach?

Comment: `multiprocessing.Pool` is a good approach when you complexify your code, as it manages most of the communication and avoid some headaches in the design for your application. Also, if you need to pass a second set of jobs, you can reuse the same `pool`. This avoid the time of launching a new set of `Process`. However, I am not a big fan of the `multiprocessing.Pool` design and I would recommend learning more about [`concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) if you are using python3 as it is more robust and the API is nicer!

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the optimal solution, and any other suggestion is much appreciated, but I managed to solve the problem as such:

```
class Worker(multiprocessing.Process):
    """Simple manual worker class to execute jobs in the queue"""

    def __init__(self, queue, success, check_success=None, directory=None, permit_nonzero=False):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.check_success = check_success
        self.directory = directory
        self.permit_nonzero = permit_nonzero
        self.success = success
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        """Method representing the process's activity"""
        for job in iter(self.queue.get, None):
            if self.success.value:
                continue
            stdout = mbkit.dispatch.cexectools.cexec([job], directory=self.directory, permit_nonzero=self.permit_nonzero)
            with open(job.rsplit('.', 1)[0] + '.log', 'w') as f_out:
                f_out.write(stdout)
            if callable(self.check_success) and self.check_success(job):
                self.success.value = int(True)
            time.sleep(1)


class LocalJobServer(object):
    """A local server to execute jobs via the multiprocessing module"""

    @staticmethod
    def sub(command, check_success=None, directory=None, nproc=1, permit_nonzero=False, time=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if check_success and not callable(check_success):
            msg = "check_success option requires a callable function/object: {0}".format(check_success)
            raise ValueError(msg)

        # Create a new queue
        queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
        success = multiprocessing.Value('i', int(False))
        # Create workers equivalent to the number of jobs
        workers = []
        for _ in range(nproc):
            wp = Worker(queue, success, check_success=check_success, directory=directory, permit_nonzero=permit_nonzero)
            wp.start()
            workers.append(wp)
        # Add each command to the queue
        for cmd in command:
            queue.put(cmd)
        # Stop workers from exiting without completion
        for _ in range(nproc):
            queue.put(None)
        # Start the workers
        for wp in workers:
            wp.join(time)
```

Basically I'm creating a [`Value`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value) and providing that to each [`Process`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process). Once a job is marked as successful, this variable gets updated. Each [`Process`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process) checks in `if self.success.value: continue` whether we have a success and if so, just iterates over the remaining jobs in the [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) until empty.

The `time.sleep(1)` call is required to account for potential syncing delays amongst the processes. This is certainly not the most efficient approach but it works.

Comment: This is the possible culprit of your ` deadlock`: `for job in iter(self.queue.get, None):`

Comment: @stovfl thanks for your response but the answer posted here works fine. I believe the issue to have been with `while not self.queue.empty()` and `self.queue.get()`, i.e the `queue` was not empty, went in the loop but upon `get()` it was empty and deadlocked.

Comment: Didn't see any `while ...`? BTW: Are you aware of `module multiprocessing.Pool`? Seems you reimplemented `Pool`.

Comment: @stovfl I did use it in the original question. As mentioned in this post, this implementation solves my problem and works fine. How would I implement it using `multiprocessing.Pool`?

Comment: Read `Pool` examples, if suited your needs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers